# Git Bash の .ssh/config 内で別ドライブにある鍵ファイルを指定するには？

Tags: windows, github, ssh

**やりたいこと**
Windows10より、鍵認証経由でGitHubと接続

**分からないこと**
configファイルとid_git_rsaファイルがそれぞれ別ドライブにある時の指定の仕方

---

**Cドライブで.ssh/configファイルを作成**
id_rsaファイルを同じフォルダへ配置すると下記で接続できるのですが、

```
Host github github.com
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  User git
```

id_rsaファイルをK:\hoge\id_rsaへ配置する場合は、IdentityFileをどう指定すれば良いですか？

```
Host github github.com
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile K:\hoge\id_rsa
  User git
```

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

参考：
[公開鍵をGitHubにアップ後接続を確かめる - Qiita](https://qiita.com/shizuma/items/2b2f873a0034839e47ce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git Bash 上では、C ドライブのパスは `/c/～` のようになります。このため K ドライブが最初から認識されているのであれば `/k/hoge/id_rsa` と指定すれば良いです。

もし認識されていなければ、一度 Git Bash 関係のプロセスを全て終了させ再起動することで認識させることができます。詳しくはこちらの投稿をご覧ください: [How to register newly mounted drive in git bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5197540/5989200)。